# rspec test for return of symbol

Tags: ruby, rspec

Ok, rspec noob here...I've got a simple method and I want to test. I just want the test to say...when this method is called it returns a symbol...any pointers?

the method....

```
  def defend_corners(board)
    @board = board
    @corners = {
        :a1=>" ", :a3=>" ",
        :c1=>" ", :c3=>" "
    }
    available_moves = @corners.select{ |k, v| v == " " }.keys
    puts "random move - corners"
    @move = available_moves[rand(available_moves.length)]
    return @move
  end
```

current test....

```
  describe 'defend_corners' do
    it 'returns corner move' do
      myboard = Board.new

      @player_computer.defend_corners(myboard).should #return a symbol???
    end  
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@player_computer.defend_corners(myboard).should be_an_instance_of(Symbol)
```

or

```
@player_computer.defend_corners(myboard).should be_a_kind_of(Symbol)
```

or

```
@player_computer.defend_corners(myboard).should be_a(Symbol)
```

Comment: hmph...now where were you 3hrs ago? :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but I think something like this works:

```
@corners.keys.should_be include @player_computer.defend_corners(myboard)
```

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to say "should return a symbol" in rspec talk would you?

Comment: .should be_a Symbol      Plz make another stack overflow question if you have more to ask

Answer (score 0):

and after 2.5 hours the answer is (drum roll)....be_a(Symbol)